# CASE ... ELSE *ignore* in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use CASE in a SELECT statement that will change two values of the possible 12 in a column.

```
CASE WHEN grade = 0 THEN 'R2'
WHEN grade = -1 THEN 'R1'
ELSE --ignore--
END AS "Grade level"
```

Does anyone have any idea what to replace the --ignore-- with, so that only those two possible values will be altered? I don't really want to keep writing out separate WHENs for each value in the column.

Comment: Well, you should pick a default value, or possibly null.

Comment: There are 10 other possible values other than '0' and '-1' in the column though, so I can't use a single default or set them to NULL. I just need them to remain the same in the result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since grade is a number, you need to convert it to a character so it'll fit with `R1` and `R2`.

```
CASE WHEN grade = 0 THEN 'R2'
WHEN grade = -1 THEN 'R1'
ELSE to_char(grade)
END AS "Grade level"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `ELSE` part:

```
CASE WHEN grade = 0 THEN 'R2'
WHEN grade = -1 THEN 'R1'
END AS "Grade level"
```

Comment: I get the error "Expected CHAR got NUMBER" when I try this.

Comment: Try to convert it to number.

Comment: @Rigel1121: we have to do everything for people these days.

Comment: @Rigel1121 You can't convert `R2` or `R1` to a number. But you can convert a number to a string easily.

Comment: Or you can just remove the `ELSE`.

Comment: I don't quite understand the logic behind this error though - without the 'ELSE grade' the query works fine. Do I need to do something equivalent to CASTing grade as char?

Comment: the ELSE comes only when the two WHEN returns False. In your case, you don't have to return something when  the two WHEN is False.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want this?

```
(CASE WHEN grade = 0 THEN 'R2'
      WHEN grade = -1 THEN 'R1'
      ELSE grade
 END) AS "Grade level"
```

I hesitate to suggest this, because `grade` appears to be a numeric quantity but the `case` statement is evaluating to a string.  However, it appears to be close to what you want.

EDIT:

As expected, you need to convert something.  I would suggest:

```
(CASE WHEN grade = 0 THEN 'R2'
      WHEN grade = -1 THEN 'R1'
      ELSE cast(grade as varchar2(255))
 END) AS "Grade level"
```

However, if you want to set `grade` to the value, then you will just get another conversion error, because you cannot assign `'R2'` to a number.

Comment: I get the error "Expected CHAR got NUMBER" when I try this.

Comment: @Tommen . . . You will not be able to do what you want while `grade` is declared as a number -- you cannot set a string value to a number.

Answer (score 1):

**Depends on your complete query** maybe you could bring the reverse logic of ignore condition to `where` clause:

```
CASE WHEN grade = 0 THEN 'R2'
WHEN grade = -1 THEN 'R1'
ELSE -- 1 or any value you can put here it dose not come in result becase of where clause
END AS "Grade level"
.....
where grade in (0,-1)
```

**EDIT:** if you be able to use in where clause you can make above query more simple (reduce one `when`):

```
...
CASE WHEN grade = 0 THEN 'R2'
     ELSE 'R1'
END AS "Grade level"
.....
where grade in (0,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could put the whole thing in as a subquery in your FROM clause, then reference the column you named in a separate WHERE clause below it...

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT.....
    CASE WHEN grade = 0 THEN 'R2'
    WHEN grade = -1 THEN 'R1'
    ELSE NULL
    END AS "Grade level" 
    FROM .....
    WHERE.....)

WHERE "Grade level" is not null
;
```